# If the 1 ans is wrong among 3 or 2 ansers(options) then how it will consider??

Tags: reporting

I m new to salesforce and preparing for the exam..

I just want to know,if the 1 ans is wrong among 3 or 2 answers(options) then how it will consider?? completely wrong or will get some point??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which exam are you talking about? ADM 201?

Comment: It will completely wrong for dev-401.

Answer (score 3):

There is no partial credit given in the exams. See http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Are-all-questions-on-an-exam-weighted-equally/?q=partial+credit&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1

Comment: Thank u for your valuable note Tepsi and Daniel..surely it will useful for me..thanks agn..